# Wrapper for libeay32.dll: how to import macro?

Tags: python, openssl, ctypes

I'm writing small wrapper for OpenSLL `libeay32.dll` in Python. For majority of functions it is possible to import them as follows:

```
self.Function_Name = self._dll.Function_Name
self.Function_Name.restype = ctypes.c_int #for example
self.Function_Name.argtypes = [list of ctypes arguments]
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to import this way any macros:

`X509_get_notAfter`, `X509_get_notBefore` etc.

Any ideas, how to do it with `ctypes`?

Comment: You cannot import "functions defined as macros" because they don't exist in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I decided to answer my own question. Macro for X509_get_notAfter looks like this:

```
#define X509_get_notAfter(x) ((x)->cert_info->validity->notAfter)
```

x - is X509 structure, which contains X509_CINF structure, which contains X509_VAL structure which contain pointer to notAfter :)

So my plan is to implement whole X509, X509_CINF and X509_VAL structure within python code.

In C it looks like this

```
struct x509_st
{
X509_CINF *cert_info;
X509_ALGOR *sig_alg;
ASN1_BIT_STRING *signature;
int valid;
int references;
char *name;
CRYPTO_EX_DATA ex_data;
/* These contain copies of various extension values */
long ex_pathlen;
long ex_pcpathlen;
unsigned long ex_flags;
unsigned long ex_kusage;
unsigned long ex_xkusage;
unsigned long ex_nscert;
ASN1_OCTET_STRING *skid;
AUTHORITY_KEYID *akid;
X509_POLICY_CACHE *policy_cache;
STACK_OF(DIST_POINT) *crldp;
STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *altname;
NAME_CONSTRAINTS *nc;
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
STACK_OF(IPAddressFamily) *rfc3779_addr;
struct ASIdentifiers_st *rfc3779_asid;
#endif
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SHA
unsigned char sha1_hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
#endif
X509_CERT_AUX *aux;
} /* X509 */;
```

And X509_CINF looks like this:

```
typedef struct x509_cinf_st
{
ASN1_INTEGER *version;      /* [ 0 ] default of v1 */
ASN1_INTEGER *serialNumber;
X509_ALGOR *signature;
X509_NAME *issuer;
X509_VAL *validity;
X509_NAME *subject;
X509_PUBKEY *key;
ASN1_BIT_STRING *issuerUID;     /* [ 1 ] optional in v2 */
ASN1_BIT_STRING *subjectUID;        /* [ 2 ] optional in v2 */
STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) *extensions;   /* [ 3 ] optional in v3 */
ASN1_ENCODING enc;
} X509_CINF;
```

And here is X509_VAL:

```
typedef struct X509_val_st
{
ASN1_TIME *notBefore;
ASN1_TIME *notAfter;
} X509_VAL;
```

To make whole task easier, I decided to replace all pointers to structures which I don't want to access with ctypes.c_void_p

So my python code looks now like this:

```
class X509_val_st(ctypes.Structure):

_fields_ = [('notBefore',       ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('notAfter',        ctypes.c_void_p)]


class X509_cinf_st(ctypes.Structure):

_fields_ = [('version',         ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('serialNumber',    ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('signature',       ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('issuer',          ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('validity',        X509_val_st),
            ('subject',         ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('key',             ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('issuerUID',       ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('subjectUID',      ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('extensions',      ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('enc',             ctypes.c_uint)]


class X509_st(ctypes.Structure):

_fields_ = [('cert_info',     X509_cinf_st),
            ('sig_alg',       ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('signature',     ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('valid',         ctypes.c_int),
            ('references',    ctypes.c_int),
            ('name',          ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('ex_data',       ctypes.c_int),
            ('ex_pathlen',    ctypes.c_long),
            ('ex_pcpathlen',  ctypes.c_long),
            ('ex_flags',      ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('ex_kusage',     ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('ex_xkusage',    ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('ex_nscert',     ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('skid',          ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('akid',          ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('policy_cache',  ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('crldp',         ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('altname',       ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('nc',            ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('rfc3779_addr',  ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('rfc3779_asid',  ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('sha1_hash',     ctypes.c_char),
            ('aux',           ctypes.c_void_p)]
```

And the last step: to assign structure to the pointer received from function X509_new():

```
self.X509_new = self._lib.X509_new
self.X509_new.restype = ctypes.POINTER(X509_st)
self.X509_new.argtypes = []
```

So python function for OpenSSL macro X509_get_notBefore will look like this:

```
def X509_get_notBefore(self):
    return self.X509[0].cert_info.validity.notBefore
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't import macros. What you're importing are functions from a DLL. Macros aren't exported from the DLL, so there's nothing to import.

Fortunately, most macros are very simple, so you can just reimplement them in Python.

Or, alternatively, create a wrapper DLL in C that defines a function for each macro, compile and link that, and import the wrapper functions with `ctypes`.

Or you may want to use [`Cython`](http://www.cython.org) or some other technology instead of `ctypes`. The way they generally work is to generate and compile C code that wraps the C library and exports Python types and functions, and it's generally as easy to export a C macro as a Python function as it is to export a C function.

Or, simplest of all… does [PyOpenSSL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL) already wrap everything you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to learn how to import dlls using ctypes. This is why I'm not going to use PyOpenSSL or M2Crypto. Regards!

Comment: @Marek: OK, that's a perfectly good reason to not use `PyOpenSSL`, and to use `ctypes` instead of `Cython`. So that leaves you the first two answers (reimplement the macros in Python, or create a wrapper DLL that exports functions for the macros); do whichever you feel more comfortable with. The good news is, you've learned something new about `ctypes` and DLLs, which was the whole point, right?